# Raw field disappear in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have my ELK installed and use a logstash file to configure the log txt files. However, when I open kibana, I could not see the .raw field data. How can I see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may go to the elasticsearch forum to ask